# C++ Back-propagation on a Graph; heterogeneous vectors?

Tags: python, c++, vector, neural-network

I've successfully written a few neural nets in the past. I've written a multi layer perceptron with fully connected layers (of any sizes and quantities) and trained it with backprop. I've done a convolutional net, and found its gradients with hand written/calculated math. I'm trying to be more general now. I want to write backpropagation for any computational graph, in the spirit of Theano.

Consider this Python code:

```
from __future__ import division
from pylab import *
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.children = []
        self.parents = []
        self.state = []
    def forward_prop(self):
        for child in self.children:
            child.forward_prop()


class Static(Node):
    def __init__(self, *shape):
        super(Static, self).__init__()
        state = zeros(shape)

class MatrixProduct(Node):
    def __init__(self, w, x):
        super(MatrixProduct, self).__init__()
        self.w = w
        self.x = x
        self.state = [0]*len(x.state)

    def forward_prop(self):
        self.state = self.w.state.dot(self.x.state)
        for child in self.children:
            child.forward_prop()

class Doubler(Node):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Doubler, self).__init__()
    def forward_prop(self):
        self.state = [s*2 for s in self.state]
        for child in self.children:
             child.forward_prop()


a = Static()
a.state = array([2,3])
w = Static()
w.state = array([[1,2],[3,4]])
x = MatrixProduct(w, a)
a.children.append(x)
d = Doubler()
d.state.append(3)
x.children.append(d)
a.forward_prop()
print a.state
print d.state
```

I see mostly how to port that to C++. My problem is I can't figure how to have the forward propagation of children work in C++. In Python, it's easy, because children is a list of potentially heterogeneous types, each with their own forward_propagate behavior. In C++, what do I do?

I feel like the answer is inheritance, but if they're all some base class, then it calls the base class forward propagate, not child.

I'm trying to avoid a redundancy. Nodes know what operation do to do turn their inputs into outputs. But, they can take inputs of different types as long as they're the same shape. IE, an ElementwiseVectorDoubler node could take as input and have as output any kind of node that handles vectors. Could get input from a matrix multiply, etc...But I don't want to have to have separate ElementwiseVectorDoubler classes for each specific type of 1d vector input our output.

Comment: *"if they're all some base class, then it calls the base class forward propagate, not child."* - Have you heard of virtual functions?

Comment: Yes but barely. I'll go read about that and try to apply it. Thanks!

Comment: To guard against X/Y questions: are you doing this as a personal learning exercise?  There are several good NN frameworks available that might greatly speed your development time -- if the model itself is your actual goal, rather than the education.

Comment: To be a bit clearer - the way you use your classes and the `forward_prop` method is essentially how you would do it in C++ (and some other languages such as C#) except you need to add the `virtual` (and `override` since C++11) keywords to the method.

Comment: Virtual functions will absolutely do the trick. This page was quite helpful to me: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/polymorphism/

Comment: Yes, just a learning exercise.

Answer (score 1):

Answered. Thank you UnholySheep. I just need virtual functions. http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/polymorphism/